# Validating Email Address.(domain)

Tags: regex, apache-flex, email-validation

I'm Using  EmailValidator for Validation:

```
<mx:EmailValidator id="Email_Validator"
    source="{txtEmail}"
    property="text" required="false"/>
```

And My Code is:

```
var isValidForm:Boolean=true;

    var validatorArr:Array = new Array();
    validatorArr.push(Email_Validator);
    var validatorErrorArray:Array = Validator.validateAll(validatorArr);
    isValidForm = validatorErrorArray.length == 0;
    if(isValidForm)
   {
        //.....
   }
```

It is working fine. But I want domain should be "gmail.com" if some other, validation should return false.. How can I achive this? 
I think Regular Expressions are usefull.. But I dont Know to use the same in flex?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are testing for is "gmail.com", you don't need to use regular expressions at all.  A simple

```
if (txtEmail.text.indexOf ("gmail.com") < 0) doStuff(); 
// index < 0 => address does not contain search string
```

would be enough.

Nonetheless, ActionScript 3 has the [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) class to provide regular expression functionality.  See [this tutorial](http://snipplr.com/view/6608/as3-regular-expression-basics/).

Comment: Im getting Error: `-1061: Call to a possibly undefined method indexOf through a reference with static type spark.components:TextInput.`

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed from your code that txtEmail is the name of your variable.  If it is the name of the TextInput, you'll have to replace with `txtEmail.text`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a component

```
 checkout this 



public class TextInputEmail extends TextInput
{
    private var emailValidator:EmailValidator = new EmailValidator();
    private var validator:ValidationResultEvent;

    public function TextInputEmail()
    {
        super();
        this.emailValidator.source = this;
        this.emailValidator.property = "text";
        this.addEventListener("enter", this.validate);

    }

    private function validate(event:Event):void
    {
        validator = emailValidator.validate();

        if (validator.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID)
        {
            this.errorString = "";
        } else {
            this.errorString = validator.message;
        }
    }
}
```

error strings are in build in Package.
I hope this helps you better...:-)

Comment: Ok.Thank you for information.. but my task was testing for domain is "gmail.com" or not so went with answer By weltraumpirat  :)